# Check for duplicates between jQuery elements

Tags: php, arrays, string

Does anybody know how to check for duplicate entries in a queries, where query elements are separated by comma.

Eg.

```
$query1 = email1,email2,email3; 

$query2 = email1,email2,email2;

$query3 = email4,email5,email6; 

$query4 = email7,email7,email8;
```

I need to check if there are any duplicates between each `$query` element?
Eg. If in `$query1` I found `email1`, then in `$query2` the same variable would be indicated as a duplicate and so on in all the queries.

Thank you!

Comment: There's no `$query2`, they're all `$query1`.

Comment: Are you concatenating, comparing, what!!!

Comment: You can join your variables, transform the resulting var into an array and then use `array_unique`

Comment: Create an associative array whose keys are the emakls. Use `explode()` to split the string on commas. Loop over all the emails, checking whether the key already exists in the array. If it exists, it's a duplicate, otherwise add it as a new key to the array.

Comment: What do you want to do with duplicate values?

Comment: sorry a litle bit fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use

- for separating by comma `explode(',',$query)` to get an array of entries
- then test the arrays against each other with `in_array($keyFromAnotherArray,$array)`

that should lead to the solution